# Using static functions in generics for TypeORM Active record

Tags: typescript, generics, typeorm

I am stuck with this: I have a set of functions that Read an entity from the database using the Active record functions, and filter them in a very specific way. Like for example (this is an overly simplified example, but the minimal that can reproduce the error; in real life a complex set of filters are applied to the entity)

Lets say that I want to get all the entities using a function

```
async function getUser() : Promise<User[]> {
    return await User.find(); // in real life there is a complex filter here
}
```

and then another one

```
async function getCompany() : Promise<Company[]> {
    return await Company.find(); // in real life there is a complex filter here
}
```

So I tried writing a generic but this did not work

```
async function getEntity<Type extends BaseEntity>(type: Type) : Promise<Type[]> {
    return await Type.find();
}
```

I get proper autocompletion from the IDE telling me that Type has a function .find() because Type extends BaseEntity, but I get the error `'Type' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

I've researched the error and it appears in different contexts, like mixing values with classes. But I am clearly refering to the class here, as is the "User" class the one who has the find method (not any instance; its a static method)

Please Help me I'm stuck

Comment: Why are you doing `Type.find`? Use the parameter `type`: `type.find(...);`

Comment: Cause as far as I understand it, type is an instance of Type, so static methods are not available (I get the error `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Type'.`)

Comment: Ah yeah. You... could potentially use `type.constructor.find(...)`, but I think there is definitely a method in the library you are using to get the original class in a safe way.

Comment: It does not work. `type.constructor.find(...)` throws the following error: `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Function'.`